# What is my document onLoad hander in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, edit-in-place

I want to use a plugin to make most of my models inline editable, but I don't understand the following:

> To use it, include
>   jquery.rest_in_place.js in your
>   template and execute the following in
>   your document’s onLoad handler:
>
> jQuery(".rest_in_place").rest_in_place();

http://jan.varwig.org/projects/rest-in-place

Where do I place this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They likely mean the jQuery document ready event.

Inside your `<head>` section, place a `$(document).ready();` like this.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery(".rest_in_place").rest_in_place();
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

**Or**

```
<head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(function() {
               jQuery(".rest_in_place").rest_in_place();
          });
      </script>
</head>
```

Comment: JavaScript runs without `<script>` tags now? :)

Comment: Better keep the JavaScript code separate from HTML, in other words include a .js file instead of putting it in <HEAD>.

Comment: Absolutely :) and `<head>` should be **lowercase**. Stick to the standard dude :p

Comment: @Nick - it was merely a case of `spot-the-error`. Noone noticed until you came along, so it worked :p

Answer (score 0):

The author probably meant the jQuery [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler which gets executed when the DOM (hierarchical structure of the document) is fully loaded.

Your JavaScript code should look as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rest_in_place").rest_in_place();
});
```

Note that `$` is a synonym for `jQuery` (unless you explicitly enable the compatibility mode).